# jQuery don't see my id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

This is my html(modal)

```
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div id="modal-text" class="modal-body">
                    <p id="modalMessage"> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is my jQuery

```
    $('a[href="#myModal"]').click(function () {
        if ($("#TermsConditions")) {
            $("#modal-title").html(`<h4>` + "Terms Conditions" + `</h4>`);
            $("#modalMessage").html(`<p>` + "message" + `</p>`);
        }
        else if ($("#Cookies")) {
            $("#modal-title").html(`<h4>` + "Cookies" + `</h4>`);
            $("#modalMessage").html(`<p>` + "message2" + `</p>`);
        }
        else {
            $("#modal-title").html(`<h4>` + "Privacy Policy" + `</h4>`);
            $("#modalMessage").html(`<p>` + "message3" + `</p>`);
        }
    })
```

modal should be opened when i am clicking on link
and when i click,modal should show some header and text from chosen link(id)
it will just looks like that(picture)

[image: img modal]

it just wrotes "message"...

and this is a code of my links

```
                <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline gray">
                    <li class="footerDistance" style="display:inline;"><a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" id="TermsConditions">Terms&Conditions</a></li>
                    <li class="footerDistance" style="display:inline;"><a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" id="Cookies">Політика Cookies</a></li>
                    <li class="footerDistance" style="display:inline;"><a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" id="PrivacyPolicy">Політика Конфіденційності</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it simpler.

```
$("#TermsConditions").click(function(){...});

$("#Cookies").click(function(){...});

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fetch an element by id of "modal-tile" but in your html there is not element with id "modal-title"

```
$("#modal-title").html(`<h4>` + "Privacy Policy" + `</h4>`);
         <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
```

I think you need to change code to

```
     <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title"></h4>
```

Also, you can change click method like this:

```
$('a[href="#myModal"]').click(function () {
       var clickedAnchorId = $(this).attr('id');

        if (clickedAnchorId === "TermsConditions") {
            $("#modal-title").html(`<h4>` + "Terms Conditions" + `</h4>`);
            $("#modalMessage").html(`<p>` + "message" + `</p>`);
        }
        else if (clickedAnchorId === "Cookies") {
            $("#modal-title").html(`<h4>` + "Cookies" + `</h4>`);
            $("#modalMessage").html(`<p>` + "message2" + `</p>`);
        }
        else {
            $("#modal-title").html(`<h4>` + "Privacy Policy" + `</h4>`);
            $("#modalMessage").html(`<p>` + "message3" + `</p>`);
        }
    })
```

Comment: I have also updated answer to fetch the id of the clicked anchor link inside the click eventhandler for conditionally updating the modal title and message